# python: two list creation

Tags: python, list

I am new at Python, I am trying to create two lists which take input from the user. Currently I have some working code but I believe it can still be enhanced and can be done in shorter way.

```
k1 = []
print("For 1st list enter")
for i in range(5):
    a = int(raw_input("Enter your value"))
    k1.append(a)

k2 = []
print("For second list enter")
for j in range(5):
    b = int(raw_input("Enter your values"))
    k2.append(b)
```

Comment: This question is less about how do I solve a problem, and more about how can I make my code better... there is a stack exchange forum for that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com 
The nuance is subtle, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the user entering one number at a time, a list comprehension lets you write this very concisely:

```
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(2):
    print ('For list {} enter: '.format(i+1))
    list_of_lists.append([int(raw_input("Enter your value")) for query in range(5)])
```

Sample result:

```
[[0, 5, 3, 5, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 3]]
```

The next step is to learn to handle invalid input using exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt the user to enter a whitespace-delimited string of tokens, then split that string into a list of those tokens.

For example:

`mylist = raw_input().split()`

Since you appear to be interested in up to five integer tokens, we should convert the splitted string tokens to integers, and truncate the list with a slice:

`mylist = map(int, raw_input().split())[:5]`

Note that you will need to wrap the map around a `list()` if you are using Python 3.x.

Also - you may find the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) community better suited to questions similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions:

```
In [283]: [int(raw_input("Enter your values")) for i in range(5)]
Enter your values1
Enter your values2
Enter your values3
Enter your values4
Enter your values5
Out[283]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Of course this assumes all of your input is going to be valid.

Otherwise something like:

```
def get_int():
    try:
        return int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, ValueError):
        return get_int()
```

Added exceptions. You probably don't really want the KeyboardInterrupt there, but if you want to prevent them from escaping the loop until they give you 10 numbers...

```
In [291]: [get_int() for i in range(10)]
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: a
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 56
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: a
Enter a number: f
Enter a number: g
Enter a number: dfd
Enter a number: df
Enter a number: df
Enter a number: df
Enter a number: df
Enter a number: a
Enter a number: 9
Out[291]: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 56, 7, 8, 3, 9]
```

Comment: I *almost* added exceptions, but then I was like "no one cares." Clearly I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Input : 1 4 5 6 6 7
Space seperated

Then

```
data = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

If your
Input : 1

2

4

5

There in each line then you must be having count.

```
count = 5
data = [ int(input()) for i in range(count)]
```

It is better to give space seperated inputs if it is going into single list.